# IE freezes GIF animation when DOM insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, dom-manipulation

My code has an animated GIF (loading image)

I get the html page in a variable "data" from Ajax call.

```
$("#content").html(data); // takes about 5 seconds and the GIF animation freezes since IE is single threaded.
```

**Is there a way to write the data line by line with a setTimeout / setInterval function so that the thread is released for a brief moment so that the animation continues?**

Fiddle URL:
http://jsfiddle.net/deepakssn/Kp2bM/

**Alternate solution I tried:**

```
<style>
#loading {
        background: url(loading.gif) no-repeat center center #fff;
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
}
</style>
<script src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
    function writeData(data) {
        var yourLines = data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, j = yourLines.length; i < j; i++) {            
            var x = setTimeout(function() {                
                $("#content").append(yourLines[i]);
                console.log("Line No :"+[i]+" "+Date.now());                
            }, 5000);
        }        
    }
    function ajaxLoad() {
            $.ajax({
                    url: "test.txt"
            }).done(function (data) {                        
                    console.log("success"+Date.now());
                    writeData(data);
                    //$("#content").html(data);
                    console.log("loaded data"+Date.now());

            });
    }
    ajaxLoad();
});
</script>
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while adding a 'loading' indicator for one of my projects. I used [this](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)  which solved the problem for me. Since it's not an image, it doesn't freeze.

Comment: @deepakssn And I hope you put the start and stop of spin.js in the ajaxSend/ajaxComplete callbacks.

Comment: But the website uses a gif image that looks very different and cannot be created using spin js. So did not spend too much time on spin js.

Comment: I want to use a gif image for loading. IE has only one thread at a time. Is there a way to use setTimeOut to mimic smooth loading image animation?